# anomaly polynomial of generalized Hitchin system

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-field-theory, integrable-systems

I would like to ask about mathematical background of this object. So, I am trying to puzzle out with 4d $\mathcal{N}=2$ SQFT. As far as I can gather this theroy can be described in terms of generalized Hitchin integrable system. Thus we live in the module space of Higgs pairs $\mathcal{M}$ and point of this space (in fact algebraic variety under some assumptions) is a class of pair $[(E,\varphi)]$ where $E$ is a fibered bundle associated to principal $G$-bundle on compact smooth curve $\Sigma$, $\varphi$ is a global section of $\mathrm{End}(E)\otimes K(D)$, i.e. global meromorphic form with poles along $D:= p_1+...p_k$, $(p_i \ne p_j$, if $ i \ne j)$. We also can imply further contributions on $\varphi$ such as $\mathrm{Res}_{p_i}\varphi  = A_i$ where $A_i \in \mathcal{O}_i$, $\mathcal{O}_i \subset \mathfrak{g}:=Lie(G)$ coadjoint orbit of $G$. Whether or no we have hitchin map $h:\mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{B}:= \oplus_i H^{0}(\Sigma, K(D)^{d_i})$, $h(E,\varphi) = char(\varphi)$. Could you possibly explain (or give reference) as aforesaid what anomaly polynomial is? And what is the relation between polynomial and prepotential (if it exists).